# SSRS Not repeat on new page

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-grouping

I have a report like this:
[image]

This is first page of a Resident.

So I just want to show #2 Rectangle in first page of each Resident and hide #2 in rest of pages like this:
[image]

I tried to use code:

```
Public Function IsFirstPage(resident as string, currentResident as Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.OnDemandReportObjectModel.Variable) as Boolean
    If (resident<>currentResident.Value) Then
        currentResident.Value = resident
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

and add expression for #2 as order to hide #2:

```
=IIf(Code.IsFirstPage(Fields!szFirstName.Value+Fields!szLastName.Value, Variables!currentResident), False, True)
```

It hid #2 in first page. However, I tested it by clicking Previous button and saw new issue appears: #2 is hidden till the first page.

Comment: Is your pages after first page just the detail (#3)? If so, why not put #3 in a separate page and do the paging there, first page just show the summary? Is #1 ever changing for each page? Can you post more details, like groupings etc, and what you want to achieve.

Comment: From 2nd page to last page is #1 and #3, It is grouped by each Resident Sir @thotwielder

Comment: what condition you use for split data to new page ?? if you use Grouping (show each group on each page)  you can set Visibility via using expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the best way is adding hidden fields to header of table #3 and use =Fields!yourFields.Value to get value for these fields.
I moved #1 to Header Page and used =ReportItems!yourTextBoxs.Value to get value for these fields.
After that I used this expression: `=IIF(ReportItems!txtResidentName.Value="", True, False)` to hide #1 on last page.
Hope anyone meet this issue, can resolve as well.
Thanks